# Save random forest predictions in a dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe

I want to loop over each `veg_type` and create a training and testing dataset, then fit random forest regressor to predict `fmc_mean` from satellite imagery. Using this regressor, I would like to predict a test dataset for each `veg_type` and assign it to `y_hat`. Then `y_hat` will be saved to the columns in the new `dataframe`. I tried following code, however it is returning error:

```
column_names = ["Combined", "Grassland", "Shrubland", "Forest", "test_lfmc"]
dataframe = pd.DataFrame(columns = column_names)
for veg_type in [0,1,2,3]:
    rf = RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators=25, max_depth=10, n_jobs=8)
    train, test = generate_train_datasets(veg_type)     #generate_train_datasets function that generates training dataset
    rf.fit(train[['ndvi', 'ndii', 'nbart_blue','nbart_green','nbart_red','nbart_nir_1','nbart_nir_2','nbart_swir_2','nbart_swir_3']], train['fmc_mean'])
    y_hat = rf.predict(test[['ndvi', 'ndii', 'nbart_blue','nbart_green','nbart_red','nbart_nir_1','nbart_nir_2','nbart_swir_2','nbart_swir_3']])
    print(y_hat)
    if veg_type==0:
        dataframe["Combined"]=y_hat
    elif veg_type==1:
        dataframe["Grassland"]=y_hat
    elif veg_type==2:
        dataframe["Shrubland"]=y_hat
    elif veg_type==3:
        dataframe["Forest"]=y_hat
​
    dataframe['test_lfmc'] = test['fmc_mean']
```

```
ValueError: Length of values (10784) does not match length of index (32752)
```

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: instead of using dataframe, use dict

Answer (score 0):

One of your dataframes is not the same length as the others. Check the shape of each set of predictions before adding it to the result dataframe.

Since you appear to be selecting subsets of your total dataset based on `veg_type` (using `generate_train_datasets(veg_type)`), you may need to modify that function to make sure the test sets returned are all the same length, instead of splitting based on some percentage of the subset length.

Comment: Thanks Bill, you are right, dataframes had different shape. I just needed to convert y_hat to pandas series, like this: `if veg_type==0: dataframe["Combined"]=y_hat`